Puma not accepting SSL connections
Due my client requirements I need to run my rails application on Windows Server using HTTPS protocol. I have created my certs, and attach them to my port with

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:7892 certhash={my_cert_print} appid={random_guid}

I also have added the ssl option on my development.rb file:
config.force_ssl = true

But when I execute my site with
rails s -p 7892 -e development --binding=0.0.0.0

And connect from outside using
https://server_ip:7892

I get this error from puma:
2024-06-12 17:53:01 -0300: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.> 

If I try with thin server
thin start -p 7892 --ssl

I get
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine

OpenSSL is installed on the server. What else can I do? (To leave Windows Server is not an option, sadly)

you are starting the server in development environment, my dev environment does the same thing. Try production mode.

@LesNightingill using windows server? I started in production mode and found the same
